# In SQL Server how can I return values in one table that are less than 20 miles from a coordinate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a really interesting problem I have been struggling with all day.  I have a table with an ID, Latitude, and Longitude of a location.  This is a subset of locations from a larger set of locations.

What I am trying to do is use this subset of locations and, for each location, return locations within 20 miles from the larger set using air distance.  My issue is not with calculating the air distances, that is working, my issue is with how to operate on each row like a `For` loop but with a set-based method.

So let's say this is my subset table, LocationSubset

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID |   Lat   |    Lon   |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | 41.0575 | -92.1364 |
+----+---------+----------+
| 2  | 47.0254 | -92.5723 |
+----+---------+----------+
| 3  | 38.9897 | -88.7623 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

And I am looking towards the larger table, Locations

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| ID |   Lat   |    Lon    |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 41.0575 | -92.1364  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 2  | 47.0254 | -92.5723  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 2  | 38.9897 | -88.7623  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 4  | 36.2137 | -91.6528  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 5  | 39.2643 | -123.0073 |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 6  | 39.941  | -123.0073 |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 7  | 35.7683 | -91.6528  |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 8  | 45.8406 | -91.6528  |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Let's assume, using the Haversine formula that locations 5 and 6 are within 20 miles of location 1 and locations 4 and 8 are within 20 miles of location 2.

I am looking to return something like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| ID | LocationID | Distance |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 5          | 15.4     |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  | 6          | 16       |
+----+------------+----------+
| 2  | 4          | 17.4     |
+----+------------+----------+
| 2  | 8          | 2.5      |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Each location could have zero to many locations within 20 miles and I am trying to capture this in another table.

I can add clarification if necessary.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: you could try cross joining the 2 tables and using the function in one of these answers to filter the result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude

Comment: what is ms_distance?

Comment: Sorry that's a UDF, but it's a distance calculation that takes in two sets of latitudes and longitudes and returns the distance.  Didn't realize it was a UDF until I looked closer.

Comment: You might want to check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157502/another-why-is-this-nearest-neighbor-spatial-query-so-slow/32160164#32160164

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     LS.ID, 
     L.ID as LocationID, 
     MS_DISTANCE (LS.Lat , LS.Lon, L.Lat , L.Lon) as Distance
FROM LocationSubset LS
JOIN Locations L 
  ON MS_DISTANCE (LS.Lat , LS.Lon, L.Lat , L.Lon) < 20
 AND LS.ID <> L.ID    -- if you want remove comparasion with same object
```

But you are problably better using sql server spatial functions because those allow to use spatial index. **[Spatial Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)**

Comment: My data set was a bit more complicated than I posted so it took a little effort to get it working but it appears to be running now.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT subtable.ID as ID1, subtable.Lat as Lat1, subtable.Lon AS Lon1,
    Locations.ID as ID2, Locations.Lat as Lat2, Locations.Lon AS Lon2,
    (CalculatedDistance using Lat1,Lon1,Lat2,Lon2) AS Distance
FROM subtable CROSS JOIN maintable
WHERE (CalculatedDistance using Lat1,Lon1,Lat2,Lon2)<20
```

Where `subtable` a query/view that generates your subtable

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to exclude the records that match so use that in your Join then cross apply your distance function

```
SELECT ls.Id,
       l.Id LocationID,
       d.Distance
FROM   LocationSubset ls 
       JOIN Location l ON ls.Id <> l.Id
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.MS_DISTANCE(ls.Lat, ls.Lon, l.Lat, l.Lon) Distance) d
WHERE  d.Distance < 20
```

Comment: Does that require `MS_DISTANCE` to be a table-valued function?

Comment: no.. if it was, you'd have to use something like `Cross Apply (Select Distance From dbo.MS_DISTANCE(ls.Lat, ls.Lon, l.Lat, l.Lon))`

Comment: I would use `LS.id <> L.id` instead. Because you can have different location on same place. Usually happen in my data when create multiple point in a Mall or a Building

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yeah you're right.. just noticed that.. much cleaner

Comment: Thank you, I miss that step. Hope I dont get acuse of cheating by copying someone else answer :P

Comment: Still dont understand why `cross apply` ??  Doesnt that calculate a table with all the combinations?

Comment: it's really just the same as using the function in your select statement.  but you can use the name in other places like Where.. or other table joins without typing out the function code every time

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it did add a Filter to the execution plan since it moves the filter to the `Where`, so I up voted your answer since it was shorter :)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tC4XG.png